# Postgres error for nil id on row creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We have a MySQL Rails app that we're thinking of migrating to Postgres. There's one part where we are seeding where we have the following:

```
class Tab < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "tagid"

  def self.rebuild_db
    terms=self.terms
    Tag.delete_all
    terms.each do |term|
      Tag.create! tagid: term[:tag_id], phrase: term[:phrase], tag_string: term[:tag_string]
    end
  end
```

When called from a console, I get the following error:

```
>     [1] pry(main)> Tag.rebuild_db
>       SQL (12.9ms)  DELETE FROM "tags"
>        (0.3ms)  BEGIN
>       SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("created_at", "id", "is_location_type", "phrase", "tag_string", "tagid", "updated_at")
> VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "tagid"  [["created_at",
> Tue, 17 Mar 2015 09:31:27 PDT -07:00], ["id", nil],
> ["is_location_type", nil], ["phrase", "food"], ["tag_string", "-1-"],
> ["tagid", 1], ["updated_at", Tue, 17 Mar 2015 09:31:27 PDT -07:00]]
>        (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
>     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
>     DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, food, 2015-03-17 16:31:27.235545, 2015-03-17 16:31:27.235545, null, 1, -1-).
>     : INSERT INTO "tags" ("created_at", "id", "is_location_type", "phrase", "tag_string", "tagid", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4,
> $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "tagid"
```

I obviously see the id=nil but am not sure if I'm doing something very wrong. This is really the only issue we have had so far. Why am I getting this error and how would I fix?

The table structure is the following:

```
embers_dev=# \d+ tags
                                                            Table "public.tags"
      Column      |            Type             |                     Modifiers                     | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id               | integer                     | not null default nextval('tags_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 phrase           | character varying(255)      |                                                   | extended |              | 
 created_at       | timestamp without time zone | not null                                          | plain    |              | 
 updated_at       | timestamp without time zone | not null                                          | plain    |              | 
 is_location_type | boolean                     |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 tagid            | integer                     |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 tag_string       | character varying(255)      | default ''::character varying                     | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "tags_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

#### Edit 1

```
[3] pry(main)> Tag.where(id: nil)
  Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" IS NULL
=> []
[4] pry(main)>
```

#### Edit 2

I think this issue has to do with setting the primary_key of the class to tagid which will cause MySQL to autoincrement the id value but not Postgres. Not 100% sure.

Comment: seems like one of your record in `tags` table, doesn't have `id`.

Comment: but we're creating a new tag so I shouldn't be creating the id

Comment: Seems like `Tag` model has a code which initialize `id` filed as `nil` or problem related to your migration. So, required code of Tag model and migration.

Comment: Obviously you don't have to create `id`, your earlier data of `tags` one of the record doesn't have the id. So find that and remove that record

Comment: See the output of this `Tag.where(id: null)`

Comment: Very strange that SQL `RETURNING "tagid"` return `tagid` instead of `id` because `id` is primary key. I think problem in your model. Probably it have line `self.primary_key = 'tagid'` which change primary key.

Comment: yeah, I think it's related to that maxd; I think just the tagid value is some rails automagic keyword on Postgres but not on MySQL. removing that from the create doesn't change behavior. This is why I'm so stumped (and am a total Postgres noob).

Comment: Sontya - I added an edit; we're doing a delete_all right before this so there should be nothing in the Tag table at that point.

Comment: why you delete all, on console run that query `Tag.where(id: null)` and delete returned records

Comment: thx everybody - so maxd's comment got me thinking and we have tagid set up as a primary key in this class. Even though we weren't inserting a duplicate, I am thinking that Postgres doesn't autoincrement the id value if you have another set as the primarykey